# How to call c function from shell script?

Tags: c, function

Please mention command or sample code to call c function from shell script .

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately you would need to compile the C code into an executable file, possibly with a command line interface if you need to parse arguments.  From there you can call your executable in the shell script.

Answer (score 2):

Python [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html) can be used to load native libraries and call functions that follow standard calling conventions. So if Python is available, one can do something like:

```
python -c "import ctypes;ctypes.CDLL('libc.so.6').puts('Hello from libC.')"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Tiny C compiler in immediate run mode, and run *any program* like this:

```
A=100500
tcc -run - <<<"#include <stdio.h> int main() { printf(\"Hello, %d world.\n\", $A); }"
```

Tcc is super fast and really tiny.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use this approach:

http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/51226-calling-c-function-froma-shell-script.html

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
cat >temp.c <<BLAH_END
blah
function_you_want_to_call(arg_you_want_to_pass..);
BLAH_END
gcc temp.c -llibrary_you_want_to_link_to
./a.out
```